# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while adding SASL_PLAINTEXT authentication to kafka broker

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

I am trying to configure SASL_PLAINTEXT authentication to kafka broker, below is my configuration.

```
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092

security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
sasl.jaas.config=/var/lib/kafka/config/kafka_jaas.conf
```

After starting zookeeper and kafka I am getting below exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed:
>   inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in
>   advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured
>   listeners are PLAINTEXT java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name
>   defined in advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently
>   configured listeners are PLAINTEXT
>       at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:233)    at kafka.server.KafkaConfig.validateValues(KafkaConfig.scala:1089)  at
>   kafka.server.KafkaConfig.(KafkaConfig.scala:1065)   at
>   kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:795)    at
>   kafka.server.KafkaConfig$.fromProps(KafkaConfig.scala:792)    at
>   kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable$.fromProps(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
>     at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:58)    at
>   kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)

Comment: What are you setting as `inter.broker.listener.name`? That is missing from the question

Comment: @cricket_007 i am not setting it as per kafka documentation http://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html#security_sasl_plain, it suggest only to set above parameters. do we need to explicitly set it? i believe it will pick the value of security.inter.broker.protocol if not set as per documentation. pls suggest.

Comment: I was just reading what the error was saying. `inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners`

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues while setting up kafka_listeners on kubernetes. Following is a working kafka configuration yaml snippet:

```
    env:
    ...
   - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
     value: “yes”
   - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
     value: INSIDE:PLAINTEXT
   - name: KAFKA_LISTENERS
     value: INSIDE://0.0.0.0:9092
   - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
     value: INSIDE://localhost:9092
   - name: KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME
     value: INSIDE
```

Similar issue discussed here with ssl configuration: [cant figure out setting for inter broker listener name in kafka with ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596834/cant-figure-out-setting-for-inter-broker-listener-name-in-kafka-with-ssl)

Also [this](https://www.confluent.co.uk/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/) confluence page will be helpful.