# Can't figure out setting for inter.broker.listener.name in Kafka with SSL

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka

I am attempting to configure Kafka nodes with SSL (TLS) inter-nodes and between nodes and clients but run into configuration problems. Kafka version is 2.3.0. My relevant settings are:

```
      - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
      - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
      - KAFKA_LISTENERS=LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka1:9092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://kafka1:29092
      - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=LISTENER_INTERNAL://kafka1:9092,LISTENER_EXTERNAL://localhost:29091
      - KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=LISTENER_INTERNAL:SSL,LISTENER_EXTERNAL:SSL
      - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper1:2181,zookeeper2:2181,zookeeper3:2181
      - KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE=false
      - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION=/var/private/ssl/server.truststore.jks
      - KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD=changeit
      - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION=/var/private/ssl/server.keystore.jks
      - KAFKA_SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=changeit
      - KAFKA_SSL_KEY_PASSWORD=changeit
      - KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL=SSL
      - KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH=required
```

FYI, for simplicity I copied the settings from the docker-compose file that instantiates the Kafka container. The env vars map 1:1 to properties in server.properties. During container start, these settings are applied to the server.properties file.

When I start with this configuration, I receive the following error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: inter.broker.listener.name must be a listener name defined in advertised.listeners. The valid options based on currently configured listeners are LISTENER_INTERNAL,LISTENER_EXTERNAL

When I set the *inter.broker.listener.name* property to either *INTERNAL_LISTENER*, *SSL*, *null* or empty string, I receive instead this error message:

> org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Only one of inter.broker.listener.name and security.inter.broker.protocol should be set.

I have spent a few hours on this issue. I have compared my settings to those few examples on the web that are supposed to demonstrate Kafka with SSL configuration.

Any idea?

Comment: It seems I got this working with just one listener, but not two yet. Still trying to get down to the root cause (and trying to understand Kafka's Scala code). I'll report when I have more reliable information.

Answer (score 30):

I finally figured out how to have multiple SSL listeners. I'll document this here in case someone else runs into the same issue, since working examples of multiple SSL listeners seem to be rare to non-existent. Below is my working configuration (only showing the relevant properties passed through from docker-compose):

```
ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=no
KAFKA_LISTENERS=ISSL://kafka1:9092,OSSL://kafka1:29092
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=ISSL://kafka1:9092,OSSL://localhost:29092
KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME=ISSL
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP=ISSL:SSL,OSSL:SSL
KAFKA_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH=required
```

The key to this was to NOT configure the **KAFKA_SECURITY_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL** as it is mutually exclusive with the **KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME** key.

In case of multiple listeners, it seems that the combination of **KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP** and **KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME** is what is required.